# CSS with select box - width and label

Tags: css

I have a select box that I need to style - we currently use a jquery plugin that replaces selects with divs and lists, and we want to get rid of it.

I found a [sample](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3) that is pretty close to what we want, but when I try to apply it to our select, there are a few off things. I'm a PHP developer, and CSS is NOT my thing, so I just don't know where to start looking with this. I have spent several hours fiddling with different values with no success.

This is the select box:

```
<label class="dropdown_arrow">
    <select id="address_dropdown">
        <option value="">Select a saved location</option>
        <option value="0">THISISAREALYLONGNICKNAME..........................: 602 BLOWING ROCK RD APT. 2 BOONE, NC 28607</option>
        <option value="1">TEST HOUSE: 9884 BLUEBONNET BLVD BATON ROUGE, LA 70810</option>
        <option value="2">MOM &amp; DAD: 9880 BLUEBONNET BLVD BATON ROUGE, LA 70810</option>
        <option value="3">414 N ORLEANS ST CHICAGO, IL 60610</option>
        <option value="4">NEW ADDRESS: 10 BARTON DR HOMEWOOD, IL 60430</option>
        <option value="5">1600 PENNSYLVANIA AVE WASHINGTON, DC 20500</option>
        <option value="6">Add a new address</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

This is the CSS:

```
select#address_dropdown {
    width: 515px;
    font-family: 'Interstate',sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:6px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    /* overflow-y: scroll; */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

select#address_dropdown option {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* Targetting Webkit browsers only. FF will show the dropdown arrow with so much padding. */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    select {padding-right:18px}
}


label.dropdown_arrow {position:relative}
label.dropdown_arrow:after {
    content:'>';
    font:18px "Consolas", monospace;
    color:red;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    right:15px; top:2px;
    padding:0 0 2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
label.dropdown_arrow:before {
    content:'';
    right:6px; top:0px;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    display:block;
}
```

There are two problems that I'm having.

1) The custom arrow, created with the `label:after` property isn't aligned correctly. On the original sample, it's situated so that it hides the default select box arrow. On mine, you can still see the default select arrow underneath the custom arrow.

2) The options are not inheriting the width of the parent select. When you click on it, the contents extend beyond the right edge of the select box. I had thought that the `overflow` and `text-overflow` properties would address that, but they have not.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmmyS/7L3C7/1/) of the current code. Can anyone help with these two issues? I'm sure they're very simple if you know your CSS, but it's a rare day that I have anything to do with it, and I just don't know where to start looking.

**UPDATE**

Apparently the code, which was touted as cross-browser, looks different in FF and Chrome, and is completely awful in IE9.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

IE9:

[image: IE9]

Comment: use a negative `top` on the absolute `:after` and `:before`, for example: `top: -18px;` to fix the positioning. Don't know how to change the width of a option though, I usually just have shorter options. And I do not see your default select box arrow? But the most reliable way for me so far is to style a `div` with `overflow:hidden`, have the select box with matching background in there exceeding the `div`s size so the part with the arrow is simply hidden.

Comment: The default select box arrow isn't visible in Chrome; it is in Firefox. And IE9 is just completely horrible (yes, we have to support it.) Updating OP with screenshots.

Comment: Remove `select#address_dropdown option { background: black; }` to avoid black background on IE.

Comment: @EmmyS Ah yeah, but that's exactly why I prefer to style a `div` or anything else with a `overflow: hidden` and place a larger `<select>` in there, quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/VZEv5/ It's simply the most reliable solution I have tried so far. You could then make the `<select>` transparent and have your arrow a background in the `div` (for example).

Comment: @EmmyS Or well.. this: http://jsfiddle.net/VZEv5/2/

Comment: @Marcel - thanks! It sounds like you prefer the first one, but the second one is visually almost perfect, even in IE9. Although the first one is certainly simpler... hm. What to do? In any case, thanks for both.

Comment: If you want to post one of those as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @EmmyS I was watching a movie during and I just went on styling, it's not that I prefer any, it's more that I just saved, then added some, saved some more to look more like what you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select box is a pain to style so what I usually do is style a container instead, like a `<div>` (or maybe even use the `<label>` for simplicity), use a `overflow:hidden` on it and then place a slightly larger `<select>` inside.

Without touching your HTML but adding different CSS, for example:

```
label {
  display: block;
  width: 515px;
  font-family: 'Interstate',sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  position:relative;
}

select {
  border: none;
  outline-width: 0;
  width: 560px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  color:#888;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
}

label:after {
  content: '>';
  font: 18px "Consolas", monospace;
  color: red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 12px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This should get close to what you're looking for.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZEv5/3/